# Constantly changing data

Tags: java, android, webserver

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I'm new to it all. I know you're all pretty strict here, so I did all the research I could before asking this. Unfortunately I came up empty.

I'm building an app that shows an event that occurs every three months. This event has different shows in it that change very often. That is where my app comes in, it keeps people updated on what will be happening at the event. So when the event planners change their schedule, I need it to update my users.  Pictures need to be changed too. Obviously, having them update the app is not the easiest way.

I know I could build a webpage, and have the app read off that. But I am really hoping there is an easier way than that. And if the webpage IS the only way, what is the best `api`?

So my question is; What is the easiest way to do this, so I can do more research about it?

Comment: As asked, this isn't really on topic for Stack Overflow. You have a perfectly valid, well written question, but questions such as this nature are just too open ended for our system. We're happy to help when you have a concrete implementation problem to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.parse.com/

Parse might be your best option if all you need is some basic data on a server.  You don't need to write a whole web application or scrape html off of a web page.  If you need other non technical users to write this data, you can make one "manager" version of your app and include some authentication logic (which you could also do against your Parse account).  I have done this kind of thing using Amazon S3 buckets when I didn't have the time to write a whole web app just for some very basic server interaction for a mobile app.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Parse.com works great.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to have a server that your app can talk to. I would do this in two parts that have to happen more or less at the same pace. First, I would use [Google's Cloud Messaging API](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) to do the "light lifting" - it lets your app do a small check to see if anything needs updating. Then I would set up the server. You're obviously going to need to learn how to open up connections, downloads, storage, etc.

Important thing to keep in mind though, efficiency. Be smart about the data transimitted. Keeping it simple will benefit your app (less code, more straightforward) and your users (smaller app, less data usage).

But first, do research, try stuff out and don't be afraid to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to build a webpage, you just need a server that the app can query

Comment: It may be best to just set up a web page, it would be the easiest way to make an "app" for any device.

Comment: server is best for app to code communication, webpage only makes sense if humans need to be involved